# applying ffmpeg video delogo filter with timeline editing (enable) to multiple areas and mutiple time frames doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg, filtering

I'm trying to blur many areas at different times in my video.  I'm using delogo because it seems to have the simplest syntax.  So I'm using a single -vf with multiple delogo expressions each specifying x,y,h,w of the area and enable for the time and duration to blur faces (except the first one which applies to the entire video to blur the timestamp on the bottom right.)   As I said, I don't want to get into complicated expressions and delogo is quite simple.  The first expression works just fine in removing the timestamp.  But none of the other expressions work -- none of the faces are blurred.  If I do a single expression it works OK.  So, is there a limit to the number of expressions in the -vf entry?  Is there a problem where one expression doesn't use the enable option while all the rest do?

One more thing I've noticed:  the bit rate of the input video is around 12000 while the output is around 33000.  I have set Q=2 which for other editing doesn't grow the bit rate but keeps it about the same as the input.

Here is my command:

`ffmpeg -i /media/don/OneTouch/evidence/finalx.mp4 -filter:v "unsharp, delogo=x=1500:y=918:w=330:h=95, delogo=x=1500:y=918:w=330:h=95, delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,839,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,1069,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,2019,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,2189,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,3019,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,4020,12)', delogo=x=1:y=875:w=850:h=144:enable='between(t,4368,12)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,975,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,1508,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,2126,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,2667,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,3142,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,3631,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,4145,16)', delogo=x=117:y=95:w=156:h=130:enable='between(t,4577,16)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,1189,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,1779,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,3369,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,3549,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,4488,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,4638,12)', delogo=x=120:y=935:w=1116:h=90:enable='between(t,4838,12)', delogo=x=108:y=1031:w=26:h=26:enable='between(t,0,10)', delogo=x=83:y=1005:w=1756:h=8:enable='between(t,0,10)', delogo=x=1840:y=1000:w=62:h=18:enable='between(t,0,10)', delogo=x=1745:y=1034:w=146:h=28:enable='between(t,0,10)', unsharp, eq=contrast=1.14:brightness=0.036:saturation=1.1" -filter:a "volume=5.048dB" -c:a ac3 -ab 384k -ar 48000 -vb 15000 -q:v 2 -r 30 -c:v mpeg4 -y /media/don/OneTouch/evidence/finaly.mp4`

I am using:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0york0~18.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: `between(t,839,12)` --> this requires a timestamp which is more than 839 and less than 12.  Not possible.

Comment: The way I read it, it means at 839 seconds for a duration of 12 seconds.  So you're saying it should be two values in seconds?  Also, must it be integer values in seconds, or can it be a frame numbers using n or pos?

Comment: Oh, also, why the bit rate go up so hi from 12000 to 32000?  The only difference between this edit and my normal edits is the filter and normally the bit rate doesn't go up.  In fact it goes down a bit.

Comment: `-vb 15000` and `-q:v 2` are mutually exclusive bitrate control methods meaning you can only use one or the other, but not both. If you use both one of them will get ignored. In this case `-vb` is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

@Gyan's suggestion in the comments is correct. The two values in the `between` parameter with specification of `t` are the beginning and *ending* times in seconds, not the beginning time and *duration*. I don't know why it grows the bit rate, but I lowered the `q` value to `4` and it kept it inline with the original; it all worked beautifully now.